# my vb6 application has many forms and they are not fully visible in windows 2012 r2

Tags: vb6, windows-server-2012-r2

My vb 6 application has many forms and they are fully visible in windows 7 and windows server 2008 r2 but when i try to run that same application in windows 2012 r2 standard server the forms are not fully visible,some how there resolution gets changed automatically,i have tried to change the resolution it didn't worked and also changed the theme to basic but it didn't worked(help me out here).

Comment: Right click your program, Properties, Compatibility.

Comment: Not a lot of information there.  Could be High DPI, could be almost anything. Is that the local session or an RDP session?  Is the server in Texas?  They say everything's bigger in Texas.

Comment: Yes its RDP  Session and no server is in not in texas...